# Couchbase startkey as literal value

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I am using couchbase to save objects.

The key of a document looks like this

```
"xxxx_someRandomValue"
```

For example, i can have this keys

```
aaaa_1
aaaa_2
aaab_1
aaab_2
```

I am making a view, which should return me all the documents of which key starts with literal "aaaa".

But, if i specify startKey="aaaa", it also finds for me "aaab", because it is comparing it in unicode values.

Can i force the view to return me just the documents of which key start with literal "aaaa_" ?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

To work as a prefix, this should work

```
startkey="aaaa"&endkey="aaaa\u02ad"
```

[documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-querying-selection.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with an endkey value in addition to your startkey, something like

```
&startkey="aaaa"&endkey="aaaa\uefff"
```

You can find more information about sorting here:

http://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-letter-ordering-view-queries

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
startkey=aaaa&endkey=aaab
```

Comment: It doesn't find anything because no keys ends up with "aaab".

Answer (score 0):

The API `startKey(final String KEY)` returns all the jsons whose keys (document name) are bigger or equal than the unicode value of KEY.

The API `endKey(final String KEY)` returns all the jsons whose keys (document name) are smaller than the unicode value of KEY.

So in your case startkey="aaaa"&endkey="aaab" (as suggested by avsej) should give you the desired result.

So the common sense says the API endKey is about compare the end of the key but it's false.